# When is the appropriate time to use aux instead of les?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, contractions

Les is the plural "the" so I'm confused as to why we would also need "aux" as it is used as "the" in a plural form.

Can somebody clarify when we would use each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *aux* is neither more nor less than combining *à* + *les*.

Therefore, if you find yourself writing *à* as in *at*, *to*, *in*, etc., followed by *les*, use *aux* instead of either of them.

> <strike>J'ai envoyé des lettres **à les** premiers ministres.</strike>
>
> J'ai envoyé des lettres **aux** premiers ministres.

This can even combine in unexpected places, e.g. titles of books.

> *Notre-Dame de Paris* est peu sentimentale, comparé aux *Misérables*.

It's important to know that this only applies to *les* the definite article, not *les* the direct object pronoun.

> — Est-ce que vous les lisez actuellement ?
>
> — J'ai pensé **à les** lire, mais non, pas encore.

It might sound complex, but there are no exceptions, so that's a help.

Also, the exact same rules apply to *au* (*à* + *le*), *des* (*de* + *les*), and *du* (*de* + *le*).

Comment: So I'm still a little confused. If I say: ils sont heureux ensemble parcel qu'ils jouer aux cartes. Why is it aux cartes and not les cartes.

Comment: @Stephanie In English you "play cards" but in French the verb is *jouer à* — both parts are key. You can check this on [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/jouer). You'll notice multiple entries on that page. The first couple, *jouer*, are for playing as in "The kids are playing." The next two, *jouer à*, are for games and sports. The next one, *jouer de*, is for musical instruments. And there are still more. The number is a little intimidating, but the idea is to look for the one that's most appropriate to your context. I find WordReference's notes are pretty good for that.

Comment: So when I say he likes to play cards it's "à les" as in "to the"... he likes TO play THE cards?

Comment: @Stephanie Not quite, because both of those words should be between "play" and "cards". Unfortunately it's just not going to sound good in word-for-word translation: "He likes to play [at the] cards." Funny enough, in the 19th century we used to say "I play at cards" in English too, but it died out. Nowadays this is one of the many times when we have to go beyond word-for-word translation and just accept that this is how French talks about playing a game or sport.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!! I have bookmarked that word reference page for the future  :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'm pretty sure "*j'ai décidé contre*" is an anglicism (*I've decided against it*?), I don't think I've ever seen it used in French.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Thanks! Changed the sentence.